# `this.type` : why doesn't this compile?

Tags: scala, types

```
class Foo { 
   def copy: this.type = new Foo().asInstanceOf[this.type]
   def multiply(n: Int): Seq[this.type] = (0 until n).map(_ => copy)
}
```

This code fails to compile with an error like:

```
<console>:33: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Foo]
 required: Seq[Foo.this.type]
```

I can't think of an explanation for this: `copy` returns `this.type`, 
`multiply` just calls `.copy` ... why is the result not compatible?

Is this a compiler bug, or is there an actual reason I am missing why this should not work?

Answer (score 0):

It's either a bug or a JVM limitation. To make it work, either create a type alias for `this.type` in `Foo`, or explicitly specify the type parameters for `map`.

However, I do not believe that there is a use case that necessitates a runtime cast to `this.type`. Whatever use case you have, there should be an alternative and better approach.

Comment: I agree the cast seems like a really bad idea. Also, the compiler prefers not to infer a singleton type in the absence of a constraint. `Identity(foo)` is `Foo` not `foo.type` unless `object foo`, for example.

Comment: Actually `identity(foo) : foo.type` but not `identity(List(foo).map(_ => foo)) : List[foo.type]` so it's because of the `CanBuildFrom` inference.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that type inference won't infer singletons. This is not a bug, but a conscious language design decision. You need to give explicit parameters to `map`:

```
(0 to n).map[this.type, Seq[this.type]] { _ => copy }
```

If you so desired, you *could* use the `Singleton` type bound to create a method that infers singleton types:

```
def replaceAll[In, Elem <: Singleton, Out](coll: FilterMonadic[_, In])(e: Elem)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[In, Elem, Out]): Out
= coll.map { _ => e }
```

Usage:

```
replaceAll(0 to n)(x: x.type) // Won't work without ascription, but cleaner than above
```

Also, please do not use `asInstanceOf[this.type]`. Singleton types are based on reference equality, not `equals`. Therefore, you get stuff like:

```
val foo = new Foo
val foo2: foo.type = foo.copy
foo2.isInstanceOf[foo.type] // false because foo2 neq foo
```

You may want [F-bounds](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html), instead.

Comment: but see my comment on the other answer.

Comment: Wait ... You are not saying that something like `def copy: this.type = clone().asInstanceOf[this.type]` shouldn't work, are you? Because it is working for me ...

Comment: I meant `isInstanceOf` stops working. `asInstanceOf` works fine, but it shouldn't be used that way due to how it breaks `isInstanceOf`.

Comment: I can understand why the compiler doesn't infer singleton types in general. But in this case, the OP is specifically requesting `map` to return a `Seq[this.type]`, and I don't see why the compiler shouldn't just do that - which is why it seems like a bug to me.